# Dereferencing string pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to C and I would like to know the difference between the below two snippet codes.When I try executing first one it works fine,but when I run the second one it gives me segmentation fault.Whats the reason for this behavior?

```
        printf("%c\n",*strptr++);

        printf("%c\n",*(strptr+i));
```

Here is the below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        char str[100]="My name is Vutukuri";
        int i=0;
        char *strptr;

        strptr=str;

        while(*strptr != '\0')
        {
                printf("%c\n",*strptr++);
                //printf("%c\n",*(strptr+i));
                //i++;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `i`?

Comment: *i-roll* everyone's a comic...

Comment: The second line clearly reads out of the imaginary RAM while the first reads from the real one.

Comment: I tested them in a while loop for I 0 to n

Comment: What's the value of `n`?  Is it larger than the length of the string pointed to by `strptr`?

Comment: @Vutukuri at the same time, or separately? In other words, post more code.

Comment: "I tested them in a while loop for I 0 to n" -- and you didn't include the loop in your question because ...? Here's a hint: if there are n chars in your string, you only want to loop fom 0 to n-1.

Comment: I added the code now.. Please check it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entirely different.

The first snippet prints the character at `strptr` and then increments `strptr` by one.

The second snippet prints the character at `strptr + i`.

Comment: Actually it doesn't _first_ print the character at `strptr` and then increments it by one, it actually increments it by one and _then_ prints the character at the old location _trololo_

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: how come? I'm pretty sure that's a post-increment right there.

Comment: Well the increment is done before the function is called, and the old value is sent to the function. I was just messing with you picking nits at your wording there. My comment was incorrect in saying that you don't know, since we do know, and the behaviour is well defined.

Comment: Yeah, actually you do know, I was mistaken. Side effects on arguments are done before functions are called.

Comment: "I'm pretty sure that's a post-increment right there" -- I'm pretty sure you didn't make any attempt to understand Seth's obvious and correct point and your mistake. That there's a post-increment only determines which char is printed, not when the pointer is incremented ... that depends on the sequence point, which occurs when the function is called.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the address `strptr` refers to an allocated place in memory, while `strptr + i` points to an unallocated place. If you allocate a string as

```
char s[LENGTH];
```

or

```
char* s = (char*)malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(char));
```

then you can only use the characters from `s[0]` to `s[LENGTH - 1]` (and the string itself can only be `LENGTH - 1` long, so there is place for a null terminator). In your case, the pointer `strptr + i` is probably not in the range `s...s + LENGTH - 1`.

Comment: Ah, an intelligent and useful response ... and before the OP even mentioned that s/he was looping i from 0 to n.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to replace i with 1.

- ++ operator first uses the initial value, and then it increments it.
- +operator calculates the new value and then uses it.

Comment: Unless, of course, you're running the two snippets in sequence...  In which case `i` should be 0 to replicate the behavior of the first line.

Comment: "Maybe you want to replace i with 1" -- It's very unlikely that the OP wants that. OTOH, loops over either *foo++ or foo[i] (equivalent to *(foo+i)) are interchangeable. The problem here is clearly the value of i, but the OP for some inexplicable reason omitted the context.